# UIButton Title Label Not Filling When Text Alignment Is Centered

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` and am trying to center the text. The below works, but it cuts off my button's `titleLabel` way before the end of the button. I want it to grow until the edge of the subview, i.e. a `CGRect frame` of `(8+9,button height ,button width - 8 - 9, button height)`

```
self.setDestinationButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.setDestinationButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.setDestinationButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.setDestinationButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .75;
self.setDestinationButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

UIImageView *destinationIcon = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_dot"]];
destinationIcon.frame = CGRectMake(8, 18 ,9, 9);//choose values that fit properly inside the frame of your baseButton
//or grab the width and height of yourBaseButton and change accordingly
destinationIcon.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;//or whichever mode works best for you
[self.setDestinationButton addSubview:destinationIcon];
```